# Learn iPhone & Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have search a lot for iPhone material to get started, but I found most of the stuff that divided either in iPhone development or in learning Objective-C only.

Can someone please send me links/ebooks/articles/videos where once can learn Objective-C and iPhone together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is arguably better if you learn objective-c before delving into the iphone framework (Cocoa Touch and associated frameworks).  The iphone sdk is built around objective-c and a firm understanding of the language is absolutely essential for understanding the documentation about how to use the iphone sdk.

Having said that, an excellent book that teaches objective-c and then provides an introductiojn to iphone programming is [Kochan's Programming in Objecitve-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)  This will get you up and running with objective-c in a minimal amount of time, after which you can start with [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592) for a thorough coverage of the main iphone sdk paradigms.

Comment: Well i have downloaded Programming in Objective - C but its quite comprehensive and i don't have that much time to finish it up :(

Comment: @Hunt people in a hurry to learn programming don't become good programmers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have looked very hard. Just look at the sidebar on this question and you will find plenty of questions/answers already on this site. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

There are online courses on iPhone application development on iTunesU which, to my knowledge, are aimed specifically at students that have no prior Objective-C experience.
I can recommend the course at [RWTH Aachen University](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-programming-10/id390395304) but I have heard good things about the Stanford course as well.

Comment: I couldn't find online the course from 2009 that you were linking at, so I put the link for the course from 2010.