# start learn iphone objective-c application where from?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

to all
i'm new-be in iphone sector i didn't decide to where from i start to learn and build application for iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: Ever been to developer.apple.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is lot of links are available for that.........
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928516/best-way-to-start-learning-cococa-in-iphone-or-osx-espeicaly-getting-the-big-pic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535198/best-way-to-learn-objective-c

[best site and way to start learning objective C for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421739/best-site-and-way-to-start-learning-objective-c-for-iphone)

[How to learn C and Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928833/how-to-learn-c-and-objective-c)

[learn iphone & objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646285/learn-iphone-objective-c)

also read this blog i like it
http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick response - here are [some recommendations](http://www.markj.net/iphone-development-programming-books/) from someone who has been there. But (as suggested in the comment) [see the longer responses here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c).